# BigQuery - How can I add 00:00:00 UTC to an existing timestamp?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an existing timestamp field that is returning in the below format "YYYY-mm-dd". What'd I'd like to do is hardcode hour/min/sec UTC timezone so that the values look like this:
"YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00 UTC". How can I do this in BigQuery?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [TIMESTAMP()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp) function as `TIMESTAMP(timestamp)`